# Adding Apache POI to Eclipse

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am not very good at adding anything to java so this is new to me, after spending hours on the internet I haven't found anything that I can easily understand, can anyone explain a couple things to me.

1. If I use Apache POI to create a java file and run the class on another machine will it run without Apache POI, if it won't run can anyone think of another way to write a word document using java.
2. How do I add the package to Eclipse, I download the Apache POI 3.9 src zip edition. I read that I am suppose to have 3 jar files which are not in the zip file, I tried adding the zip file to eclipse under the package properties "Add External Jar" option with no avail.

Any input is appreciated, what I am trying to do is creating a list of names from a text file and sorting that list, removing duplicates, then printing the list to a Word Document in five columns per page, if I could print in columns in a text file that would work to. Lastly, I would like to thank this community, this is an awesome website and has helped me greatly the past couple years.

Comment: Is there another way to make a list of names, 5 columns wide, with a header on each page, programmaticly? Using the javas libraries it comes with, that's all I have to work with on these work computers, it would take weeks to get the Heads to approve the JDK and Apache POI to be installed on the four office computers I need it installed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to either wait for POI 3.10 beta 3, or just grab [the latest source tree from SVN](http://poi.apache.org/subversion.html). As of quite recently, Apache POI now ships with an Eclipse project file in the source tree.

Once you've got a new enough copy of Apache POI, simply fire up Eclipse, choose <kbd>File</kbd> then <kbd>Import</kbd>. Pick *Existing Project into Workspace* then select the directory where you POI source tree is. Follow the wizard to complete the project import, then you'll be away!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need all the dependent jars on every single machine where you want to run your application. You have to add them to your classpath just as you need to do it when you are compiling your code.

The best way how NOT to manage your dependencies manually is to use a management tool like maven ( http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html ). It could take some time to understand how it works (there are lot of good tutorials available - just google for maven) . Anyway it will save you a lot of time in the future. (It can build for you a jar that includes all dependencies with simple "maven install" command)

There are very good maven plugins for eclipse. They are usually included in newer eclipse versions by default.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have poi on the other machine, but this shouldn't deter you. 
You can either just deploy the separate jars with your class file, or export the class file in a jar with the dependent jars.

You should also download the binary distribution not the source distribution, you will find the jars you are looking for in there. And then you can add external jar.

Additionally, as mentioned in another answer, if you are going to be doing a fair amount of java development, it might be worthwhile to look into maven.

Lastly, if you can get away with not writing to a word document, you could forego poi altogether and create a html file that has a 5 column table. You would create the html file the same way you create any text file.

Hope that helps.